# How to incorporate wildcards with place holder variables in Java using SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Hello the following block of code represents one of the options a user can put in to perform a query search. As is, it successfully returns when the formation name is completely spelled out. However, I am trying to make it work for partial entries as well.

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.get("formation"))) {
            nativeQueryFromAndWhereClause.append(" AND formation LIKE :formation ");
            parameters.put("formation", searchParameters.get("formation"));
        }
```

Notice ":formation" that is the place holder variable. When i try to simply add % around it, it breaks. Any tips or suggestions how I can make this work? Thanks a ton!

Comment: People obviously know what you are talking about, but what framework/api are you using here??

Comment: I apologize, I am using the Java Spring Framework and STS (Spring Tool Suite) API. It is basically eclipse but pre-configured with Maven, Apache Server, and other cool things. Very much recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this work, the wild card cannot be applied to the place holder variable. Instead it needs to be added around searchParameters.get("formation"). See example below.

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.get("formation"))) {
            nativeQueryFromAndWhereClause.append(" AND formation LIKE :formation ");
            parameters.put("formation", "%" + searchParameters.get("formation") + "%");
        }");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put quotes around it as well as follows:

```
if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(searchParameters.get("formation"))) {
            nativeQueryFromAndWhereClause.append(" AND formation LIKE '%:formation%' ");
            parameters.put("formation", searchParameters.get("formation"));
        }
```

Comment: I tried it and it still did not work, but you gave me idea which worked. I very much appreciate your answer and taking time time to help me out.